# issue using compass and zurb-foundation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Hi I have  zurb foundation and I'm totally newbie. I'm using a ubuntu 12.04 ppc (g5) machine and I did the installation from the terminal, everything went ok, but when I try to create a project using compass and Zurb-foundation, this is what is going wrong?

LoadError on line 122 of /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/../compass/configuration/data.rb: no such file to load -- zurb-foundation
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

I did sudo gedit to see if this file data.rb exist and affirmatively it does exist...so since I'm a designer not savvy on ruby or compass...what it is wrong, shaving my head in shame...any help will be appreciated.

BTW I have googled and nothing.

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to install Zurb Foundation. :)

Please execute the following command:

```
gem install zurb-foundation
```

This will install the Zurb Foundation extension for Compass.

After that, you can create your Foundation-powered Compass project.

Don't forget to study the documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Comment: In my case, that's not the problem. Compass seems to be using a wrong version of Ruby...

Comment: Неy @GarciaWebDev, do you have Gemfile in your project?

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov no, in my case i'm using Grunt and the grunt-contrib-compass plugin to build. Nonetheless, grunt-contrib-compass uses the same compass CLI bin to compile everything.